# AWK Merge lines with same first column to specific format

Tags: awk, merge, conditional-statements

I would like to merge lines of tab sep file (contatin 9 columns) by same $1 to specific format.

INPUT:

```
DIA   55tyr  10 HOM   1 olig_al  ....
ALOP  66tel  11 HET   3 alin_et  .... 
ALOP  128ryp 11 HET   3 ivi_es   ....
ALOP  131dat 11 HET   3 osi_et   ....
ANDY  12dou  13 WILD  4 sas_rar  ....
KOLIK 16dev  14 HET   6 levi_lol ...
```

OUTPUT:

```
DIA   55tyr  10 HOM   1 olig_al  ....
ALOP  66tel_128ryp_131dat 11 HET_HET_HET 3 alin_et_ivi_es_osi_et ....
ANDY  12dou  13 WILD  4 sas_rar  ....
KOLIK 16dev  14 HET   6 levi_lol ...
```

A could merge it and write lines one by one in one line with this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}'
```

and after that use some conditions. Is it way to write awk code to merge lines with same $1 and join $2,$4,$6,$7,$8,$9 with separator "_" and $3 and $5 line will be uniq like in output?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one.

`b[]` is the array where you store the field numbers that need to be appended together with `_`s, `a[$1]` holds the data record for identical `$1`s and is rebuilt every time `$1` is met again.

Regarding *$3 and $5 line will be uniq* the program assumes that they stay constant (like in the sample) and are taken from the last seen instance of `$1`.

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    b[2];b[4];b[6];b[7];b[8];b[9]                   # these fields are appended
}
{
    if($1 in a) {                                   # search if in a already
        n=split(a[$1],tmp,"\t")                     # split on a tab from a
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {                         # iterate all elements
            if(i in b)                              # if appending needed
                $i=tmp[i] "_" $i                    # append
            a[$1]=(i==1?"":a[$1]) $i (i==n?"":"\t") # and rebuild a entry
        }
    } else                                          # if not in a
        a[$1]=$0                                    # well put it in
}
END {                                               # in the END
    for(i in a)                                     # iterate 
        print a[i]                                  # and output
}' file
```

Output:

```
ANDY    12dou   13      WILD    4       sas_rar ....
DIA     55tyr   10      HOM     1       olig_al ....
KOLIK   16dev   14      HET     6       levi_lol        ...
ALOP    66tel_128ryp_131dat     11      HET_HET_HET     3   alin_et_ivi_es_osi_et   ...._...._....
```

**Update:** Adding a one-liner version (just in case:)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {b[2];b[4];b[6];b[7];b[8];b[9]}{if($1 in a) {n=split(a[$1],tmp,"\t");for(i=1;i<=n;i++){if(i in b)$i=tmp[i] "_" $i;a[$1]=(i==1?"":a[$1]) $i (i==n?"":"\t")}} else a[$1]=$0}END {for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Its not flexible regarding number of columns. `...` may mean x more columns. Also the `for(i in a)` should not be used, since it messes up the sorting. Better to use `for (i=1,i<=counter;i++)`

Comment: It is flexible as long as the `NF` stays constant. `for(i=1;...)` won't work as-is as the index of `a[]` is a string, without adding another array to hold another (sparse)  index.

Comment: `b[2];b[4];b[5];b[6];b[7];b[8];b[9] ;b[xxxx]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean?

Comment: What is in the BEGIN block?What if you have 100 field?

Comment: The `b[]` stores the field numbers that need to be appended by `_`. The others are taken from the first stored record--which I now noticed apparently wasn't the intention (_uniq in output_, whatever that means). Thanks. Too bad the sample did not reflect that.

Comment: I tired it like one liner but I received : awk: line 1: syntax error at or near for
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near else

Comment: Added a one-liner version.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution(To concatenate all fields with same first field):*** Could you please try following. This will take care of sequence of $1 in which this is coming this will show output in same manner. Also this will run till maximum number of fields(in whole Input_file).

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  val=val>NF?val:NF
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    c[$1,i]=(c[$1,i]?c[$1,i] "_":"")$i
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s ",b[i])
    for(j=2;j<=val;j++){
      printf("%s %s",c[b[i],j]?c[b[i],j]:0,j==val?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
DIA 55tyr  10  HOM  1  olig_al 
ALOP 66tel_128ryp_131dat  11_11_11  HET_HET_HET  3_3_3  alin_et_ivi_es_osi_et 
ANDY 12dou  13  WILD  4  sas_rar 
KOLIK 16dev  14  HET  6  levi_lol
```

---

---

***2nd solution(To concatenate only even fields):***

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  val=val>NF?val:NF
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
    c[$1,i]=(c[$1,i]?c[$1,i] "_":"")$i
    }
    else{
        c[$1,i]=$i
    }
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s ",b[i])
    for(j=2;j<=val;j++){
      printf("%s %s",c[b[i],j]?c[b[i],j]:0,j==val?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
DIA 55tyr  10  HOM  1  olig_al 
ALOP 66tel_128ryp_131dat  11  HET_HET_HET  3  alin_et_ivi_es_osi_et 
ANDY 12dou  13  WILD  4  sas_rar 
KOLIK 16dev  14  HET  6  levi_lol
```

Comment: @Vonton, Sorry I did't get it, which thing is not working? For your samples this code works just fine.

Comment: @Vonton, in case your file is tab delimited then you could add field separator as `\t` in your code.

Comment: @Vonton, it did work for me, could you please post few output lines here and I could check it once.

Comment: Here is the first line: `DIA 55tyr       DIA 10  DIA HOM         DIA 1   DIA olig_al     DIA ....       DIA 0` ANd with tabs (`$I`) in place: `DIA 55tyr ^IDIA 10 ^IDIA HOM ^IDIA 1 ^IDIA olig_al ^IDIA .... ^IDIA 0`

Comment: @JamesBrown, Sir fixed it now(ASAP reached home), `printf("%s ",b[i])`  should be in 1st for loop NOT in 2nd, lemme know please if this worked for you sir?

Comment: @Vonton, I had fixed it now, please check and lemme know. This should be more flexible. This should be able to Handle more number of fields + this will give output in same order in which Input_file $1 is coming, lemme know how it goes now?

Comment: @Vonton, Could you please do let me know if these solutions helped you?

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13, now it is working great. Thank you too for your help and solution of my problem. Best Vonton

Comment: @Vonton, Your welcome happy that it helped you, you could give up-votes for encouraging people on SO for their good answers too, cheers and happy learning.